# JW player 7 HTML5 and flash ads

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am currently upgrading from JW6 to JW7, and I am having a hard time figuring out the ads' behavior.

1. If I set the `rendering Mode` to HTML 5, will the player be able to play flash ads?
2. If I set the `rendering Mode` to flash, will the player be able to play HTML 5 ads?
3. When `rendering Mode` is set to HTML 5 will the player be able to load both HTML 5 and flash ads?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JW7 the rendering mode affects which media provider is used - `"html5"` is the default. Setting `renderingMode` to `"flash"` will attempt to use a swf to render video before falling back to a video tag. Ads are rendered using the same provider as the current playlist item when possible.

- When playing video with Flash, Flash is used to render video ads. In JW Player 7.2 HTML5 VPAID2 ads will play over the Flash provider, and banner overlays will always be rendered in html.
- When playing video with HTML5, ads that require Flash to play cannot be played. JW Player does not overlay HTML5 video with a swf to play ads.